# \substack in \tag error

Tags: amsmath, labels, tags, substack

For some reason, using `\substack` as a label's tag causes such errors

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
p+q=w \\
a+b=c \label{eq:1} \tag{$\substack{a\\a}$}
\end{gather}

\eqref{eq:1}

\end{document}
```

However anything else, even math like `\vec{a}` inside `\tag` works perfectly fine.

Why does `\substack` do that and how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with texlive 2022  you get

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\protect ->\noexpand \protect 
                              \noexpand 
l.9 \end{gather}
                
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

with texlive 2021

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\restore@math@cr ->\def \math@cr@@@ 
                                    {\cr }
l.9 \end{gather}
                
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

With 2020 you get the error you show

```
! Use of \math@cr@@ doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...ved@d = #1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.9 \end{gather}
                
?
```

With the current texlive 2022 you can use `\protect`. That also worked in 2021, but not the older texlive 2020 release.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
p+q=w \\
a+b=c \label{eq:1} \tag{$\protect\substack{a\\a}$}
\end{gather}

\eqref{eq:1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do with texlive 2019?

Comment: @antshar probably `\tag{$\protect\substack{a\protect\\a}$}` (that works in 2020, I don't have 2019).  In 30 years of latex use, I think it's the first time I have ever seen anyone use a two line `\tag` what is the use case here?

Comment: I just wanted to create sequential tags with asterisks i.e ∗, ⁑, ⁂, but didn't mentioned that because someone could write a pseudo-solution based on using unicode characters instead, but I need `\substack` because of it's versatility.

Comment: Thanks, this code with multiple `\protect`s works well. I think it worth adding it to the answer too.